# Django REST undefined JSON

Tags: jquery, json, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to accomplish a country name autocomplete with Django's REST framework and AJAX. The relevant parts are here:

```
#---- views.py -------------
@api_view(['POST'])
def get_country(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    #JSON to serializer object
    serializer = CountrySerializer(data=request.data)
    if (serializer.is_valid() == False):
      return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    req_name = serializer.validated_data['country_name']
    matching_countries = Country.objects.filter(country_name__icontains = req_name )[:20]
    country_json = {}
    country_json['country_name'] = []
    for c in matching_countries:
      country_json['country_name'].append(c.country_name)
    return JsonResponse(country_json) 


// ---- client side call
function get_country(query, process) {
          $.ajax({
            url: 'get_country/',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
              country_name: query
            },
            success: function (response) {
              s = response.data;
              console.log(typeof(eval(s)));
            }
          });
        }
```

The request seems to work, if I check the response in the chrome developer tools, I get something like:

```
{"country_name": ["BHUTAN", "HUNGARY", "LITHUANIA"]}
```

The problem is that the response object seems to have undefined type. The line console.log(typeof(eval(s))); prints undefined in the console. I tried various ways to parse, stringify, but none of them seemed to work. Any idea on what is going on? I have to keep the above structure for the response to plug it in another function later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs, the `success` function has this signature:

`Function( Anything data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )`

For example:

`success: function (data, status, xhr) {
    console.log(data.country_name[0] === 'BHUTAN');  // Prints true
}`

Comment: for some reason it worked in this example (last one on the page) with one parameter: https://docs.handsontable.com/0.24.2/demo-autocomplete.html, but your suggestion solved my problem. thanks a lot!